# Link in image is not working on full image

Tags: html, css

My link which would go to the home page is on the Egypt coat of arms. But the link is only clickable on the nav bar. How do I fix it? The first block is HTML and the second is CSS.-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

[html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pqqWO.png)

[css](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wSVwW.png)

```
(HTML)
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="coatofarms"> <a href="home"><img src="coabetter.png" class="coa" width="75px"></a></div>
<div class="topnav">
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  <a href="#about">About</a>
</div>
<button type="button"class="buttonbook" >BOOK</button>
<div style="padding-left:16px">
  <h2></h2>
  <p></p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

```
(CSS)
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background-image: url("goodyegypt.png")
}

.coatofarms {
    margin-top: -16px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    width: 5%;
}

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #e1bc85;
  margin-top: -151px;

}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-left: 10%;
  font-family: Bodoni Mt;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.topnav a.active {
  background-color: #04AA6D;
  color: white;
}


.buttonbook {
background-color: #e9cda4;
border-radius: 50%;
width: 250px;
height: 100px;
border: none;
opacity: 0.7;
font-family: Algerian;
font-size: 30px;
margin-top: 35%;
margin-left: 43%;
align: center;
}

.buttonbook:hover {
    background-color: #e1c295;
    opacity: 0.7;
}
```

Comment: Don't use images for code. Please post the actual text.

Comment: add the href, whether page name like home.html or page id like #home

Comment: Hi iGanja I tried that and it didn't work. It seems like the nav bar is stuck to the image. Do you know how to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

The use of margin-top as the only layout mechanism is what is causing you problems. In this fiddle I instead absolutely placed your button.buttonbook element.

https://jsfiddle.net/cwzp5dya/2/

```
.buttonbook {
position: absolute;
top: 55%;
left: 43%;
```

Highly recommend NOT using margin as your primary layout method.